# Pluck with Where condition

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

I can take the list using

```
$specialities = Speciality::pluck('name','id')
```

Why isn't the following code working? What could be an alternative? 
I am returning this array by ajax to form a select box. So I thought `pluck` (list in laravel 4+) would be the right choice.

```
$specialities = Speciality::pluck('name','id')->where('role_id',$request->roleid);
```

Comment: Is [tag:pluck] the right tag for this question? When I hover over it, it says that pluck is a Rails function.

Comment: Oh yes. Just now i am also noticing it. I think the pluck has the same meaning in both rail and laravel. But there is no separate i can find for laravel pluck. What should i do?

Comment: I'm not sure myself. Just trying to probe for answers from people. I can't find a pluck for laravel. Since you say that it is the same in rail and laravel, maybe you can just keep it.

Comment: `$specialities = Speciality::where('role_id',$request->roleid)->get()->pluck('name','id');`?

Answer (score 74, accepted):

I found the mistake. I should use pluck with where condition like below.

```
$specialities = Speciality::where('role_id',$request->roleid)->pluck('name','id');
```

Pluck won't filter anything, but it gives only what needed. So filtering has to be done before that.